# Cannot start Apache Geode server - MemberStartupException

Tags: geode

I am trying to follow this [instruction](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/115/getting_started/15_minute_quickstart_gfsh.html) and start Geode locator and server. Locator starts properly:

[image: Locator started]

But when I try to start a server, I get this exception:

[image]

Yesterday I got same exception, but started a server properly after rebooting my PC. But today it doesn't help, I tried twice.

What can be wrong here? What should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend faced the same problem in the same task, and we solved it this way:
Just restart your PC and try to start locator and server. After multiple tries it's gonna start and never fail again.